# Iptables rule to match on mac address fails

Tags: iptables

Why is the following simple IPtable rule not working?

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.88 -m mac --mac-source 00-27-0E-33-4B-B2 -j DROP
```

Actually I want to inverse the match. Something like this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.88 -m mac ! --mac-source 00-27-0E-33-4B-B2 -j DROP
```

As I got an error there, I tried to remove the ! just to see if I was doing something syntactically wrong with the placement of the !.  I see that the problem is not related to ! as removal of it does not help.

The error I get is:

```
 iptables v1.4.21: ether
 Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to supply the MAC address in the form xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx, not with dashes in between. I.e.:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.88 -m mac ! --mac-source 00:27:0E:33:4B:B2 -j DROP
```

I usually also use lowercase but I think that doesn't matter.

Comment: Yes it worked! At least the syntax error went away. I think that may be it was parsing the "-" as some option. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Take care that mac address should be specified using `:` instead of `-` :

```
00:27:0E:33:4B:B2
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but to no avail. In any event, the reason I want to do that is to ensure that the MAC address and the IP address do match, as assigned.

Comment: @Samir Answer edited

Comment: @krishFR I am not sure if both the correct answers were given at the same time or what... It just says 1 hour ago for both. Just used my own logic to mark wurtel's answer as accepted. I may be wrong. If so, sorry.